# Windows 10 Realtek Audio Console and ACER Laptop

Tags: windows-10, realtek-hd-audio

I have an ACER laptop and want to use the Realtek Audio Console.

I run it in Windows 10 and it says it cannot find the RPC Service.

I find out I need the Realtek Audio Universal Service Driver 1.0.0.338 for Windows 10 which I download.

I also download the latest version of the Acer AUD driver for ACER motherboards from here: https://www.station-drivers.com/index.php/en/outils/Drivers/Realtek/Audio/Realtek-High-Definiton-Audio-(HDA-UAD)/Drivers-(UAD)/Acer/lang,en-gb/

I made sure to download the UAD versus the HDA drivers.

So, I downloaded the Realtek Audio Universal Service Driver 1.0.0.338 for Windows 10 and I extracted it and there is an .inf file, .cat file and .dll file.  How do I install this universal service driver ?  Can I ?  I tried to install it as the Realtek audio driver and it wouldnt let me - so I how can I Install this ?

Does the audio from realtek depend on the motherboard so this is all for not ?

Comment: 1) have you seen [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/realtek-audio-console-not-opening-gives-error/428d86bd-0fac-46d7-8a8f-eac9a4543e0b) post? 2) NEVER.. ever never ever never download drivers from some random "driver-net.com" or in your case "station-drivers.com".  How can you trust them? (hint.. you can't).  Go to the SOURCE or secondarily go to the company that made your system.  You are inviting a virus onto your system (COME ON IN MR VIRUS!).

Comment: Ok thanks.    But how would I find and install these drivers otherwise ?

Comment: It's a laptop, so audio chip is on the motherboard. The "where" is "from Acer website". What you downloaded is a  LONG way from "latest" Acer release anyway, AFAIK it's 6.0.9180.1 with UI 1.27.253.0. Maybe [this](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/588107/realtek-audio-problems-or-want-new-realtek-audio-drivers-follow-this-predator-pt917-71) discussion in Acer community helps you. I found it by putting your title in Google.